# 2 Cancel buttons on Xeditable angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I'm using [xeditable](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-table) angular directive.Could you tell me how to use 2 cancel buttons ? B'cos I need to implement 2 functionalities on it.I mean `cancel + my work 1` and `cancel + my work 2`. Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<form editable-form name="tableform" onaftersave="saveTable()" oncancel="cancel()">

//UI code here

<button type="button" ng-disabled="tableform.$waiting" ng-click="tableform.$cancel()" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>

</form>
```

**JS**

```
// cancel all changes
  $scope.cancel = function() {

  };
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/78/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have 2 cancel buttons within the form and pass the form as attribute. Then in the corresponding cancel functions you can invoke form.$cancel and then do your logic. `form.$cancel` does the same work as invoking `ng-click="tableform.$cancel()"`.

***Play with it : [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lmD4msacDxa1ZrEQuvNl?p=preview)***

```
  //html
  <button type="button" ng-disabled="tableform.$waiting" ng-click="cancel1(tableform)" class="btn btn-default">cancel 1</button>
  <button type="button" ng-disabled="tableform.$waiting" ng-click="cancel2(tableform)" class="btn btn-default">cancel 2</button>

  //controller
  $scope.cancel1 = function(tableForm) {
    // Call tableForm cancel to reset
    tableForm.$cancel();
    //Logic1
  };

  $scope.cancel2 = function(tableForm) {
    // Call tableForm cancel to reset
    tableForm.$cancel();
    //Logic2
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should be able to take control of how the cancel button function. If you take carefully into the code you will see that, they just create some buttons and display or hide them base on the current form status(form.$visible)

Do something like this.

```
 <button type="button" ng-disabled="tableform.$waiting" ng-click="tableform.$cancel()" class="btn btn-default">cancel1</button>
    </div>
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/80ngz7u9/2/)

Comment: How can I give 2 functionalities on 1 event according to your example ? You have used `oncancel` event only.

Comment: I need to implement 2 methods or behaviours on those events (i.e. on 2 cancels events).

Comment: In this case, I think you may have to create an e-form with a name for each of your span so that you can have access to $cancel method for each form

Comment: No.That way it won't work.B'cos I need to access the same form's properties using both `cancel` buttons.Cannot use 2 forms.